# Create public facing SugarCRM form to create contact

Tags: sugarcrm

How can I create a publicly facing SugarCRM form in order to enter a contact into the SugarCRM database?

Do I need to create my own form and create queries to insert the fields into the appropriate customer tables or is there a stream lined way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Check out Sugar's Web-to-Lead, you can create a basic form through the Campaigns module.  Although this will post the data into the Leads module, not Contacts.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to create your custom form. Then when form submit, send REST/SOAP call(set_entry) to create new contact.

You need to know that web-to-lead for only create lead record(campaign is also required int that case).